# Return top search results with unique title in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have search results produced by Elasticsearch as follows:

query: apple pie

```
1. title: apple pie, score: 144.67503
2. title: apple pie, score: 128.19138
3. title: apple, score: 59.768208
4. title: apple, score: 39.49909
5. title: red apple, score: 34.314064
6. title: apple red, score: 34.014064
```

I want to have the following:

```
1. title: apple pie, score: 144.67503
2. title: apple, score: 59.768208
3. title: red apple, score: 34.314064
4. title: apple red, score: 34.014064
```

How can I do that in Elasticsearch? It would be great if get the response in DSL.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "title": {
            "value": "apple pie"
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "titleAgg": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "title",
            "order": {
               "scoreAgg": "desc"
            }
         },
         "aggs": {
            "scoreAgg": {
               "max": {
                  "script": "_score"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This query shall give you title in **key** and score under scoreAgg aggregation as **value**

Comment: I wonder, how can I add this aggregation query in a pipeline, where the score is generated by function_score.